# help changing fstab for hdd external

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, external-hdd

Is there a program that will help with fstab. Not sure how to mount a external harddrive with defualt options.

Need help changing fstab for hdd. I screwed up editing mount options.

Mounting with termimal this happens:

```
mount /dev/sdc

mount: /dev/sdc: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

Mounting with Disks this happens:

**Error mounting filesystem** Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1: unknown filesystem type 'nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

**Error removing old** /etc/fstab entry Didn't find entry to remove (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Thank you.

Comment: You don't mount the whole disk, but a partition in most of the cases. And you need to specify a mount point.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html

Comment: It seems fairly clear that the format of what you've added to your fstab is wrong. If reading the manual page for it as above does not help, then please show us the current contents and we'll tell you what is wrong. Based on the error message yuo are probably missing the filesystem type which would normally be in the third column.